# Custom WebRTC SDK for Android

Tags: android, webrtc

I am trying to develop my own sdk webrtc for android based on WebRTC.
I have my own signalling server and STUN/TURN server.

I need pointers on how to start to develop the sdk which the third party developers will use to develop their apps using my sdk.
Currently, I am exploring the WebRTC sdk and the demo app for android.

Mine specific questions are:

1. How would I provide the SO(libjingle_peerconnectcion_so.so) and JAR(my own java implementation for signalling and STUN/TURN and other app specific things) files together as one JAR file?
2. Is there any other alternative for the above said scenario?

Any help/resources are welcome.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could check these projects whose aim is to provide a cordova plugin for WebRTC (both for iOS and Android):

https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc

https://github.com/remotium/cordova-plugin-webrtc